# wordpress styles doesn't work in custom theme, only html tags are get affected

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a custom theme in wordpress. when i change some styles in the blog editor( eg: color, size, layout... ). the html tag classes changes but it doesn't affect the website

i tried layout columns. the html class gets changed like this

```
<div class="wp-block-columns has-2-columns">
    <div class="wp-block-column">
...
```

but it still one column no style changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer.

I just forgot to add wp_head(); inside head tag